# Grace period for Schengen visa

Tags: france, schengen-visas

I have a valid Schengen visa for 90 stay of duration valid form 21/09/2018 to 19/03//19. Is there any grace period associated to Schengen visa? This is because my flight back home is on the 94th day of my stay.

Just saying this is my 5th Schengen visa, and have been a holder of the residence permit previously of France, but haven't had such issues before thus I am looking for advice.

Comment: From your other questions I guess you have in Indian passport. But I can not work out whether you have a single entry or multiple entry visa. Extra days over 90/180 are usually not allowed. (Not an answer as I am no specialist.)

Comment: The visa rules are not affected by your own choice to schedule your departure 4 days beyond the allowed duration of stay.

Comment: Your best bet is to go to the UK or some other non-Schengen destination for five days.  But be careful about counting days; many people get it wrong.  For example, if you go to the UK on Friday and return to the Schengen area on Sunday, you delay your departure deadline by only one day.  See https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en.

Answer (score 5):

No. A kind of "grace period" is given when the validity period exceeds the duration of stay, so that the visitor can adjust the travel dates without a new visa, but exceeding the duration of stay beyond the 90/180 rule requires a national D visa or other special cases. (Some nations have bilateral treaties preceding the Schengen rules, which were "grandfathered" in.)